# Es Posible hacer que un ng-repeat vuelva a correr al actualizar datos?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design

tengo una app en angular pero tengo el siguiente lio.

El menu de la app esta en blanco y luego de loguearse llama una funcion que trae el menu habilitado para el usuario. El problema es que no se actualiza el menu, es como si el ng-repeat no tomara el cambio que sufrio el scope.

Como podria corregirlo? Estoy usando Angular-Material

```
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <h2><span>Inspecciones</span></h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-menu ng-repeat="menu in vm.menu">
       <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">{{menu.title}}</md-button>
           <md-menu-content>
               <md-menu-item ng-repeat="subm in menu.subm">
                   <md-button ng-href="#/consultaInspector">{{subm.name}}</md-button>
               </md-menu-item>
           </md-menu-content>
   </md-menu>
</div>
```

Esta es la Funcion que me trae el Menu.

```
function menus() {
   if (OrganismosService.authentication.isAuth != false) {
          MenuService.ConsultaMenus(OrganismosService.authentication.userName)
             .then(function (data) {
                 vm.menu = data;
             })
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que llena los datos en el menú del usuario. Estoy casi seguro que el problema está ahí.

Comment: @devconcept ya mismo lo hago.

Comment: @devconcept ya actualice

Comment: Esto es raro porque el código parece estar bien. Haz probado hacerle un `console.log(vm.menu)` justo despues de asignarlo? Me parece que debería ser `vm.menu = data.data` ya que los datos del servicio `$http` traen la información en una propiedad llamada `data`.

Comment: @devconcept si en el console los datos estan bien, yo pienso que el problema es con el ng-repeat, pq la primera vez corre bien el ng-repeat y pinta todo, pero cuando corro la otra funcion y cambio los valores del ng-repeat no me cambia los valores, como si el ng-repeat no volviera a correr.

Comment: Imagino que porque la otra función no se realiza en el contexto del angular. Edita la pregunta y añade el código de la otra función que llamas. Si la actualización se produce dentro de un ciclo `digest` la directiva `ng-repeat` siempre se actualiza

Comment: Cual es la lógica que tiene el método `MenuService.ConsultaMenus`, es una llamada a `$http`? Pon el código de ese método para que podamos verlo.

Comment: Logre Solucionarlo, resulta que al llamar el controller se crea un segundo como en memoria, la solucion fue dejar los datos en un service, y luego llamar los datos desde hay al ingresar, todo funciono ok.